# Macro to copy a Named Range from one Worksheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have several Named Ranges that contain constant data in one worksheet.
I have a target range where one of the Named Ranges will be copied to, on another worksheet.

The Named Range that will be copied is selected based on user input into other cells. 
I have managed to create the name of the relevant Named Range in a single cell.

What I can't do (as I'm a VBA Noob who thought he could do all this without using VBA!), is create a Macro that reads the relevant cell, and then copies whatever Name Range it reads, into the target range.

Any assistance most humbly and gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, the name of your range is `MyRange`

So to copy the range you have to do this

```
Range("MyRange").Copy
```

Now let's assume that Cell A1 of `Sheet1` has the word `MyRange`. In such a scenario, you can retrieve the value of the cell A1 using `Range("A1").Value`

So

```
Range("MyRange").Copy
```

becomes

```
Range(Range("A1").Value).Copy
```

Here is a complete example. I am assuming that you want to copy to say Cell A1 of Sheet2

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    wsI.Range(wsI.Range("A1").Value).Copy wsO.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Siddharth I will try this out hopefully by Monday.

Comment: Great educational step by step answer!

Comment: Hi @siddharth I tried this but it does not seem to work - no errors are generated when I step through it but it does not do the copy.

Comment: This is my actual macro in case I used an incorrect reference:

Comment: Sub CopyWSAmount()

    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
 
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lookup")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Information")
 
    wsI.Range(wsI.Range("lookup!C29").Value).Copy wsO.Range("WageSubsidyAmounts")
End Sub

Comment: IT'S FIXED AND WORKING - I am so impressed with everyone who contributed - MANY MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if thats what you need, but, if you need just to copy the content of the A1 cell from sheet1 to sheet2 for example, just do this:

```
Plan2.Cells(1, 1).Value = Plan1.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

you may wnat to encapsulate the code into a sub as well:

```
Sub copyvalues()
Plan2.Cells(1, 1).Value = Plan1.Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

...and finally, you must to insert a button, using onclick() event to fire the sub(which you must to allocate into a module)

sorry my bad english, hope it helps you.

Comment: Ah! I have just realised one of my named Ranges was incorrect - and now it looks like something is happening, except what is ending up in each cell is the word TRUE, instead of the contents of the "from" cells...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function copyNamevalues(srcName As Name, destName As Name)
    srcName.RefersToRange.Cells.Copy (destName.RefersToRange.Cells)
End Function
```

Comment: Please add some comments to your answer to give it some context